# Display text in Quill editor

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, quill

when I try to set text which contains "\n". It displays error - **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL** in browser console

In java script console I get my text as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var toolbarOptions = [
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
    //['blockquote', 'code-block'],

    [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }],               // custom button values
    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    //[{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }],      // superscript/subscript
    [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }],          // outdent/indent
    //[{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction
    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme

    [{ 'align': [] }],

    ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
  ];
  var quill = new Quill('#standalone-container', {
      modules: {
      toolbar: toolbarOptions
    },
    theme: 'snow'
  });
  var quill1 = new Quill('#standalone-container1', {
      modules: {
      toolbar: toolbarOptions
    },
    theme: 'snow'
  });

  $(".tacti_note_txt").click(function(){
    $("#order_video_01").get(0).pause();
  })

  $(".tech_note_txt").click(function(){
    $("#order_video_02").get(0).pause();
  })

  $(document).ready(function(){

    // my element which display errors
    var technical_notes = '<%= raw @review.technical_notes %>';
    quill.setText(technical_notes);

    var tactical_notes = '<%= @review.tactical_notes.to_s %>';
    quill1.setText(tactical_notes);

  });
</script>
```

I want to display text as below in editor:

```
  'Rails
   and
   quill
   editor
   ;
```

Comment: Show browser's `var technical_notes...` line plz

Comment: `\n` symbol may break that line to multiple lines. Try to use `\`\`` string instead of `''` string

Comment: @Dimava, I got error at here ->  var technical_notes = '<%= raw review.technical_notes %>';

Comment: Here Problem is editor need text like "uhgfjgfjvj\r\nghjghjghjhgj\r\nghj\r\nghj\r\nhg\r\njghj\r\n" . and my databse also saves the same. But on page while display that text it consider enter instead of "\n" and that is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(my_string)** - worked for me.

As it keep my string with \n and  \t, So quill editor display it in proper format as:

```
 'Rails
   and
   quill
   editor
   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess but you may need to use escape character `\`  so try `"\\n"`

**EDIT:**

Use `"<br/>"` tag instead of `"\n"`

Comment: Try "<br/>" tag instead of \n?

Comment: Replace text with <br/> tag is not good option, as My text is dynamic